# Is there any way to implement validation for file upload using class-validator?

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, class-validator

I am using [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) for validate data, I need to implement validation for file upload. Ex: file is not empty (It would be great if also implement file must be image).

I try in following way:

```
export class FileModel extends Model {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    file: File

    constructor(body: any) {
        super();
        const {
            file,
        } = body;

        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

But it's always return "file should not be empty" even I select file. is there any way to implement validation for file upload.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: at the top of my head shouldn't that be `@isNotEmptyObject()` instead?

Comment: where you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom class-validator [custom validation decorator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators):

```
interface IsFileOptions {
    mime: ('image/jpg' | 'image/png' | 'image/jpeg')[];
}

export function IsFile(options: IsFileOptions, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        return registerDecorator({
            name: 'isFile',
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            constraints: [],
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: {
                validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
                    if (value?.mimetype && (options?.mime ?? []).includes(value?.mimetype)) {
                        return true;
                    }                        
                    return false;
                },
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The preceding custom decorator just checks the mime-type of the file. You can write a more sophisticated implementation and also add file size check and etc.
You can use the custom-decorator like this in your DTO classes:

```
class UploadImageDto{
    @IsFile({ mime: ['image/jpg', 'image/png']})
    file: any;
}
```

Furthermore if you are using class-validator in NestJs you can use [`nestjs-form-data`](https://github.com/dmitriy-nz/nestjs-form-data) library which contains `@HasMimeType`, `@IsFile`, `@MaxFileSize` and more file validation decorators out of the box.